# Getting `panic: os: invalid use of WriteAt on file opened with O_APPEND`

Tags: go

I am a newbie to Go. Was starting to write my first code in which I have to download a bunch of CSV's from AWS. I don't understand why it is giving me the below error with O_APPEND mode. If I remove `os.O_APPEND`, I only get the last file data which is not the objective.

The objective is to download all CSV files into one file locally. I'd like to understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

const (
    AccessKeyId     = "xxxxxxxxx"
    SecretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Region          = "eu-central-1"
    Bucket          = "dexter-reports"
    bucketKey       = "Jenkins/pluginVersions/"
)

func main() {
    // Load the Shared AWS Configuration
    os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", AccessKeyId)
    os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", SecretAccessKey)
    filename := "JenkinsPluginDetais.txt"

    cred := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey, "")
    config := aws.Config{Credentials: cred, Region: aws.String(Region), Endpoint: aws.String("s3.amazonaws.com")}

    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&config)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //list Buckets
    ObjectList := listBucketObjects(sess)

    //loop over the obectlist. First initialize the s3 downloader via s3manager
    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

    for _, item := range ObjectList.Contents {
        csvFile := filepath.Base(*item.Key)

        if csvFile != "pluginVersions" {

            downloadBucketObjects(downloader, file, csvFile)

        }

    }

}

func listBucketObjects(sess *session.Session) *s3.ListObjectsV2Output {

    //create a new s3 client
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    resp, err := svc.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket),
        Prefix: aws.String(bucketKey),
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return resp

}

func downloadBucketObjects(downloader *s3manager.Downloader, file *os.File, keyobj string) {

    fileToDownload := bucketKey + keyobj

    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(Bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(fileToDownload),
        })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Downloaded", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the definition of [`s3manager.Downloader`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Downloader.Download):

```
func (d Downloader) Download(w io.WriterAt, input *s3.GetObjectInput, options ...func(*Downloader)) (n int64, err error)
```

The first argument is an `io.WriterAt`; this interface is:

```
type WriterAt interface {
    WriteAt(p []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
}
```

This means that the `Download` function is going to call the `WriteAt` method in the `File` you are passing it. As per the documentation for [`File.WriteAt`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.WriteAt)

> If file was opened with the O_APPEND flag, WriteAt returns an error.

So this explains why you are getting the error but raises the question "why is `Download` using `WriteAt` and not accepting an `io.Writer` (and calling `Write`)?"; the answer can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Downloader.Download):

> The w io.WriterAt can be satisfied by an os.File to do multipart concurrent downloads, or in memory []byte wrapper using aws.WriteAtBuffer

So, to increase performance, `Downloader` might make multiple simultaneous requests for parts of the file and then write these out as they are received (meaning it may not write the data in order). This also explains why calling the function multiple times with the same `File` results in overwritten data (when `Downloader` retrieves the each chunk of the file it writes it out at the appropriate position in the output file; this overwrites any data already there).

The above quote from the documentation also points to a possible solution; use an [`aws.WriteAtBuffer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#WriteAtBuffer) and, once the download is finished, write the data to your file (which could then be opened with `O_APPEND`) - something like this:

```
buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
numBytes, err := downloader.Download(buf,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(Bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(fileToDownload),
        })

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
_, err = file.Write(buf.Bytes())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

An alternative would be to download into a [temporary file](https://pkg.go.dev/os#CreateTemp) and then append that to your output file (you may need to do this if the files are large).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I don't get it why do you even need `os.O_APPEND` flag in the first place. As per my understanding, you can omit `os.O_APPEND`.

Now, let's come to the actual problem of why it's happening:

Doc for `O_APPEND` (Ref: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

```
O_APPEND
              The file is opened in append mode.  Before each write(2),
              the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as
              if with lseek(2).  The modification of the file offset and
              the write operation are performed as a single atomic step.
```

So for every call to `write` the file offset is positioned at the end of the file.

But `(*s3Manager.Download).Download` supposedly be using `WriteAt` method, i.e.,

Doc for `WriteAt`:

```
$ go doc os WriteAt

package os // import "os"

func (f *File) WriteAt(b []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
    WriteAt writes len(b) bytes to the File starting at byte offset off. It
    returns the number of bytes written and an error, if any. WriteAt returns a
    non-nil error when n != len(b).

    If file was opened with the O_APPEND flag, WriteAt returns an error.
```

Notice the last line, that if the file's opened with `O_APPEND` flag it will result in an error and it's even right because WriteAt's second argument is an offset but mixing `O_APPEND`'s behaviour and `WriteAt` offset seeking might create problem resulting in unexpected results and it errors out.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation. Really appreciate it. Now my issues is when i omit 'O.Append'. i get output of the last csv file that is in the aws. i want to download all the csv files...